# What are some ways in which multiple php scripts can run from a single script?

Tags: php, curl

I am having a problem with multiple php scripts running from a single script. Call my initial script, script A, and the file it is in file A.php. 
In A.php, I have {php code, and html code}. The html code is a form which I submit and then process in another file, call it B.php. I expect the processing to end there, and an output from B.php to show up. However, I end up going to file C.php, even though I did not include that file or require it.

For some basic pseudocode that shows what each file does...:

<kbd>A.php</kbd>

```
-- php stuff
-curl.exec function that goes into file B
html stuff
```

<kbd>B.php</kbd>

```
-- php class myClass
myClass = new myClass();
myClass->someFunction(); //returns some value
```

<kbd>C.php</kbd>

```
--some other php stuff
```

Is this a bug in cuRL, or a bug in my code?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get a (useful) answer.

Comment: Curl is nothing but an HTTP download tool. It has no way to interfere with the execution of remote PHP scripts. Plus, can't you just run your script directly? Why do you need to use Curl as proxy?

Comment: I think it's good idea to prepare sample code to show problem live.

Comment: not really sure on your structure or your terminology but sounds like you're posting to the wrong page, url or whatever you're using :S

Comment: *"Is this a bug in cuRL, or a bug in my code?"* ... how on earth are we supposed to know whether there's a bug in your code when you've only posted pseudo-code?